# Не работает код biopython

Tags: python, biopython

Пытаюсь освоить biopython, всё установил, нашёл учебник.
Там просят запустить этот код:

```
from Bio.SeqIO import parse 
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord 
from Bio.Seq import Seq 

file = open("example.fasta") 

records = parse(file, "fasta") for record in records:    
   print("Id: %s" % record.id) 
   print("Name: %s" % record.name) 
   print("Description: %s" % record.description) 
   print("Annotations: %s" % record.annotations) 
   print("Sequence Data: %s" % record.seq) 
   print("Sequence Alphabet: %s" % record.seq.alphabet)
```

example.fasta выглядит так:

```
>sp|P25730|FMS1_ECOLI CS1 fimbrial subunit A precursor (CS1 pilin) 
MKLKKTIGAMALATLFATMGASAVEKTISVTASVDPTVDLLQSDGSALPNSVALTYSPAV
NNFEAHTINTVVHTNDSDKGVVVKLSADPVLSNVLNPTLQIPVSVNFAGKPLSTTGITID 
SNDLNFASSGVNKVSSTQKLSIHADATRVTGGALTAGQYQGLVSIILTKSTTTTTTTKGT 

>sp|P15488|FMS3_ECOLI CS3 fimbrial subunit A precursor (CS3 pilin) 
MLKIKYLLIGLSLSAMSSYSLAAAGPTLTKELALNVLSPAALDATWAPQDNLTLSNTGVS 
NTLVGVLTLSNTSIDTVSIASTNVSDTSKNGTVTFAHETNNSASFATTISTDNANITLDK 
NAGNTIVKTTNGSQLPTNLPLKFITTEGNEHLVSGNYRANITITSTIKGGGTKKGTTDKK
```

Консоль выдает ошибку:

```
records = parse(file, "fasta") for record in records:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! :(

Comment: Уточните заголовок

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам стоит перенести цикл `for record in records:` на новую строку?))

Должно быть так:

```
records = parse(file, "fasta") 
for record in records:    
   print("Id: %s" % record.id) 
   print("Name: %s" % record.name) 
   print("Description: %s" % record.description) 
   print("Annotations: %s" % record.annotations) 
   print("Sequence Data: %s" % record.seq) 
   print("Sequence Alphabet: %s" % record.seq.alphabet)
```